# blur(); on middle mouse click

Tags: javascript

I've searched google, this and other forums, but to no avail… sooooo, is it possible to have something like onMiddleClick="blur();" to hide the focus border of a link on middle mouse click?

Comment: I don't understand what a link's `focus border` is, what am I missing?

Comment: Nvm did some research and found: http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/06/10/sharpen-your-site-by-removing-unwanted-link-border-outlines/ I never knew they had a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 2) {
        $(this).blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: I want it to be in effect for any anchor tag…

Comment: Ooooh, ok, wasn't sure of the proper syntax for that, thanks!

Comment: No problem. And if later you want it to be only links with class `no-focus` then it would be `a.no-focus`

Comment: Ok, oddly enough, this only affects non-webkit browsers. But the solution didn't work in IE9/FF4. When I middle click a link, a new tab opens and the link receives focus (which I don't mind) but the focus border pops up, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Anybody out there have any ideas on why this is?

Comment: I was having problems on one of my websites when I removed all the anchor tags and replaced them with click event handlers. Everything worked great except on IE9/FF4 (Windows *only*) which, on middle click, would go against set browser behaviour and open up in a new tab and put focus to that tab immediately. I'm not sure if you are having a similiar problem but these two situations could possibly be related, not sure how to fix yours though :/

Comment: How did you go about fixing that situation?

Comment: I put the anchors back and instead of doing any click event handling I did hashchange event handling, letting the browser decide when to open the links in a new tab (when doing click handling I checked if there was a middle click and then called window.open which was messing with the browser)

Comment: Cool, thanks!!! I don't _think_ it'll remedy my specific problem, but I'll give it a go and let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS...

```
#element:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

Comment: @Connor It will never show the outline, but not exclusively to middle click.

Comment: It doesn't entirely answer the OP's question but thanks for it anyways I never knew what a `focus border` was or how to get rid of it ahah